# Restrict Record Create to Custom Button Only

Tags: lightning-aura-components, relationships, create-records

I would like to restrict the way my users can create a custom object record. Specifically, this object record is a child of a different object and should never be created without a reference to the parent. For a couple reasons, I don't want to create a Master/Detail relationship.

So my first thought is to create a quick action on the parent account. However, I don't like this option because [quick actions require the record type to be selected](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4U9AAI), and we have about 10 different record types. I don't want to create a button for each.

So that leaves me with the option of creating a custom button/component. I can create a pretty simple component and replace the New button for the object. If on the parent object, it can easily reference the parent object record. My concern is that the [object tab would still have the option to create a new child record](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq6yAAC), without reference to the parent. The only way to remove that is to change the object permissions. If I do that, would my custom button/component allow users to create a new record?

I know the easiest way to make this work would be to require the lookup field on the child object, but I am hoping there is a better way. Could I create the component and limit create access on the object? Would that work? Or is there a different option I have not considered?

Comment: Requiring the field is likely the best solution in this case.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably correct. Thanks as always, @sfdcfox